# Filtrar con LIKE en mongoDB usando PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Tengo que filtrar una lista de usuarios. Si el atributo dato está vacío listará toda la lista de usuarios. Mi duda viene con cómo usar lo que sería un like en SQL pero desde PHP, o si hay alguna forma de "insertar" comandos de mongo desde el lenguaje.

El código que pretendo hacer es este, lógicamente no funciona la parte del like, pero para que entendáis mi idea.

```
        public static function listarUsuarios($dato) {
        $conexion = ConexionBd::getInstance()->getConexion();

        if ($dato == ""){
            $filter = [];
        } else {
            $filter = ['email' => "%".$dato."%"];
        }
        $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);
        return $conexion->executeQuery("Plataforma.Usuarios", $query);
    }
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: No necesitas usas los wildcards `%`. Intenta construir el filtro así: `$filter=array( 'email'=>new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex("$dato") );` y luego:  `return $conexion->Plataforma->Usuarios->find($filter);` De todos modos no queda claro en tu código qué debería ocurrir cuando `$dato` no tiene nada. ¿Le pasas un filtro vacío? Sería una situación poco convencional.

Comment: Me ha servido mucho tu respuesta. Lo del filtro vacío lo hago así porque `$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);` necesita o bien recibir un filtro o no recibir ningún parametro y para no hacer la misma línea dos veces, con o sin. No sé si es la mejor práctica, si hay una forma mejor de hacerlo me gustaría saberlo. Gracias

Comment: Revisando la documentación el parámetro para filtrar es opcional, por tanto no debería haber ningún problema entonces si el filtro está vacío. En cuanto a una mejor práctica no sabría decirte, tampoco soy experto en MongoDB.